# Regular expression for java

Tags: regex

I have 2 regular expressions that I want to combine.

**First Regex:**

```
(?:for invalid user|for user|user|for|to account) (?:\"|')?(\\S+?)(?:\"|'|'s|,)?(?:\\.|\\s.*?)$
```

This regular expression captures the username from this string:

> <37>May 14 10:02:10 imapd[7336]: [ID 210418 auth.notice] Login failed
>   user=k33360 auth=k33360 host=bas3-stlambert20-1176368555.dsl.bell.ca
>   [70.29.245.171]

**Second Regex:**

```
(?:\\w*\\:?\\s?\\[ID \\d+ \\w+.\\w+\\]\\s*(\\w*)?.*?)
```

This regular expression captures the username from this string:

> <33>Jul 16 07:55:44 sudo: [ID 702911 auth.alert]   do0905 : 1
>   incorrect password attempt ; TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/do0905/bin ;
>   USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/su -

Now I want to combine both of these regular expression with the OR condition, so that it is `true` for both the string.

I have tried using this regular expression, but it doesn't work:

```
(?:for invalid user|for user|user|for|to account) (?:\"|')?(\\S+?)(?:\"|'|'s|,)?(?:\\.|\\s.*?)$ | ((?:\\w*\\:?\\s?\\[ID \\d+ \\w+.\\w+\\]\\s*(\\w*)?.*?))
```

How can I combine these two regular expressions using the OR condition?

Comment: doas you regexes really works? because they acctualy match different parts of your input strings... one match ID, another try to match user name. So give us examples of input and output data, show us what you whant to get

Comment: Hi, Actually I was looking, when first event come then parse id and when second event come the parse user name with same regular expression, thats what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to combine it like this:

```
Pattern.compile("(?i)(?:for invalid user|for user|user|for|to account)(?:\"|')?(\\S+?)(?:\"|'|'s|,)?(?:\\.|\\s.*?)|((?:\\w*:?\\s?\\[ID \\d+ \\w+.\\w+]\\s*(\\w*)?.*?))");
```